# Get new Height and Width of Widget after manual resize

Tags: gridster

After a make a manual resize of my widget using

```
gridster.resize_widget ( _widget_container , size_x , size_y);
```

I need to get the new widget size, but I get always the old height. I need to wait a few miliseconds to get the correct new height and width.

There is any way to get an event when Grister has complete the resize widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In current version of gridster you can add a callback function to resize widget:

> .resize_widget( $widget, [size_x], [size_y], [reposition], [callback] )

You can read details in the [gridster](http://gridster.net/#resize_widget_method) page.